# Is there an analogue of the word "parity" for infinite/finite?

Tags: terminology

We say that two integers have the same parity if they are both even or both odd. Is there a word like this but for infinite/finite instead of odd/even? That is, if a quantity $X$ is finite if and only if a quantity $Y$ is finite, can I express this by saying that $X$ and $Y$ have the same [fill-in-the-blank]? Something sort of like "order of magnitude", but where the only two orders are "infinite" and "finite".

Context: I'm writing a paper in probability, and I want to talk about comparing the expectations of two random variables. One is infinite if and only if the other is infinite. If there isn't a word for what I'm looking for, that's fine, I can say it some other way, but I feel like there should be a word for it.

Comment: finitude (need to type 15 characters more for stackexchange to accept the comment)

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide a source using finitude in that way? If I look at Wiktionary, for example, it doesn't list that usage. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/finitude

Comment: this isn't quite what you're looking for, and I don't think it's standard, but I've seen the notation $|A|\dot{=} |B|$ or ($\kappa\dot{=}\lambda$ where $\kappa,\lambda$ are cardinals) to mean "either $A$ and $B$ are both infinite or $|A|=|B|$"

Comment: also, @hunter's suggestion is a good one; even if it's not commonly used, you could just add a short "notation" section to the start of your paper and say something like "we say that two random variables have the same *finitude* when the expectation of one is infinite iff the expectation of the other is too"